# Admin panel in django is not working

Tags: python, django

I have this miniblog,
I run " manage.py runserver " in cmd,
and run " http://127.0.0.1:8000/ " in browser its open my Home/index page,

but the problem is when "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin" it won't redirect,
is the problem with URL.py ?
Thank you for your time,
AC

Comment: The problem might be with your `urls.py`, but we can't tell because you haven't included it in your question.

Comment: Can you please update question with your urls.py file ??

Comment: What error you have received. Try making the debug mode true in `settings.py`, it will give more details in solving your issue

Answer (score 0):

In you project/url.py, make sure you have this :

```
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```